# AJAX works fine but PHP won't receives data

Tags: php, jquery

This is one of the weirdest problems that I've seen

Ajax sends datas correctly (I guess) but Php won't receives them

I've tried to change url to current page and it returns me empty and the success functions returns me the source code !

```html
    <div class="test">
        <h3>test</h3>
    </div>
```

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("div").click(function () {
           let folderName=$(this).children("h3").text();
          $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url:"post.php",
              data: {id:folderName},
              success:function (data) {
                  alert(data)
              }
          });
          });
       });
```

```php
 var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: Your question, while valid, is very incomplete. I suggest your browse [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and reconsider the code posted.

Comment: class="t"est that's weird, did you mean class="test" ?

Comment: _"Ajax sends datas correctly (I guess)"_ - You should make sure by doing some basic debugging. To begin with, do a `console.log(folderName)` before your `$.ajax()`-code and see if it contains what you expect. Then, open the network tab in your browsers dev tools and check what the request sends and what the response is.

Comment: @DylanKas yes My bad

Comment: Show us your file structure. Your code should work so probably the error is  in your path.

Comment: @pr1nc3 the path is correct I'm sure because the success alerts the source code of the file (!)

Comment: Then the error is somewhere else cause i tested your code locally and works fine. In the pop up i can see the h3 text.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I did that , the folder name is correct and it sends the request but I'm not sure sends it correctly but It show that a request has been send

Comment: @pr1nc3 I'm kinda losing my mind LOL, I've been searching this about 1 hour and I still don't know what is the problem

Comment: can you try `print_r($data);`

Comment: If you go to the network tab in your browsers dev tools, make the ajax request and you should be able to see _exactly_ what it sends and what the response is.

Comment: @pr1nc3 - There is no variable called `$data` in the OP's code.

Comment: Data is just the output of the php function. In this case the output of the $_POST.

Comment: @pr1nc3 - What "php function"? Are you seeing some code I'm not? All the PHP-code does in the posted code is to dump `$_POST`. Where are you asking the OP to add `print_r($data)`?

Comment: Yes i was referring to this `var_dump`. Locally tested it prints in the pop up the header text. So basically i can't reproduce OP's problem. I mean this var_dump should be in inside `post.php` file since OP mentioned that the url path is working fine, but OP's code works fine for me.

Comment: _"I've tried to change url to current page and it returns me empty and the success functions returns me the source code !"_ - Why wouldn't you get the source code? An ajax request is simply doing an ordinary request. If you request a page with a lot of HTML, that will be returned. That only proves that your ajax-code works.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Shouldn't it returns the output of code ? It just alert me "var_dump($_POST)"

Comment: If you have that code in the top of the page with an `exit;`, then yes. Otherwise, no. The server can't possibly know what you want to return. As far as the server is concerned, it just got a request to a file and will execute and return it like it would for any other request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending the ajax request in current page which contain the html code. In response you will get source code of that html page.

To resolved this issue add the Ajax request functionality on top of page.

post.php will be like.

```
<?php
//Start ajax request
if($_POST['id']){
        echo $_POST['id'];
        exit;
}
?>
<!-- Start HTML COde --->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("div").click(function () {
       let folderName=$(this).children("h3").text();
      $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"post.php",
          data: {id:folderName},
          success:function (data) {
              alert(data)
          }
      });
      });
   });

</script>
<div class="test">
    <h3>test</h3>
</div>
```